# #UWP get system theme (Light/Dark)

Tags: windows, uwp

how to get windows system theme in UWP?
Light/Dark

```
var DefaultTheme = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
WindowsThemeText.Text =DefaultTheme.UIElementColor(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIElementType.PageBackground).ToString();
```

i've tried that , but it doesnt shows theme....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

uiTheme will return only two color #FF000000(Dark)or #FFFFFFFF (Light) according to system ui theme, so you can go this way.
you can fill dark or light color to your some ui element to show current system theme

```
var DefaultTheme = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
var uiTheme = DefaultTheme.GetColorValue(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.Background).ToString();
if(uiTheme == "#FF000000")
{
    WindowsThemeText.Text = "Dark";
}
else if(uiTheme == "#FFFFFFFF")
{
    WindowsThemeText.Text = "Light";
}
/*
else
{
    WindowsThemeText.Text = "Some new Updated theme found";
}
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your confirming and editing my code to right direction!

Comment: Unfortunately this will return the "app theme", but not the "windows theme" - they can be different. This can be important when choosing a color for Live Tiles

Comment: @tipa The default app theme is returned, which it got from the system.
If the app changes this theme, this is not reflected in new UISettings().

Comment: @MichaelB that's not what I meant. In the Windows settings you have 3 options for the "Theme": Dark, Light and Custom. When you select Custom, you can specify a different Theme (Light or Dark) for both Windows and Apps. Now, with the code above the "app theme" is returned, but not the "Windows theme" (which is what I would call "(Windows) system theme" as asked by the creator of this question)